# Installing a git repo via nuget

Tags: git, visual-studio, nuget, definitelytyped

I just installed `React.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped` via nuget and rather than the expected [github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/react](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/react) I received [github.com/wizzard0/react-typescript-definitions](https://github.com/wizzard0/react-typescript-definitions) which is both out of date and incomplete.
Is there a way I can install the 'official' DefinitelyTyped version of the package (presumably via a git url?) to my project's packages.config or do I need to manually vendor the files?